# Restrict or Obscure data sent to Application Insights

Tags: asp.net-web-api, system.diagnostics, azure-application-insights

we have just added Application Insights to our WebAPI 2.2 application and it looks like a winner.
However, we have some controllers that receive sensitive information that we cannot store due to compliance regulations, even in Application Insights. We want to capture information level trace events on some of our controllers, but we need to not capture or obscure the information when sent through other controllers. Can anyone suggest a way that we can achieve that?

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit? Do you mean not collecting request data for requests to specific controllers? Or not collecting some fields of the request?

Comment: We are collecting TRACE information from all the controllers. Some of the TRACE events include the json payload. This is useful on some of the controllers but on other controllers the payload contains sensitive information that we MUST NOT store due to our compliance requirements. We need a way of disabling application insights for those specific events.

Comment: Are you referring then to using the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener package?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. This is the first time I have used this so I am still learning my way around the terminology - apologies :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question on the Azure MS website and got a reply that works well.

Anyone looking here for an answer should look there.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-get-started/#comment-2309233065

Comment: that comment is not there anymore, what was the response they gave you? Was it about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#filtering ?

Comment: Hi, @dgaspar The comment was referring to version 1 of application insights, which is probably why its no longer there. I cant recall the details and I have moved jobs since I posted this question. The link you provided is for version >= 2. It looks like it should do exactly what I wanted and I would have used that at the time if it was available. It looks like a good choice if your problem is similar to mine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener package, I don't think there's any way to directly filter the data. If you can add something special to the Trace.WriteXxx() call, then one option might be to implement a [TraceFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracefilter(v=vs.110).aspx) and register it through your configuration for the ApplicationInsights Trace Writer.

Then in your [TraceFilter.ShouldTrace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracefilter.shouldtrace(v=vs.110).aspx), you could check for that special value (maybe it's the event ID, maybe some prefix in the trace message, or something like that) and simply return false to cause it to be skipped.

Comment: Thanks tomasr. I'll look into that idea.